# Imbalanced data for multiclass classification with ConvNet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, unbalanced-classes, smote

I am trying to apply the SMOTE sampling technique to over-sample the minority class of a multiclass (5-class) problem using the convolutional neural network. As far CNN requirement, the input shape for all instances should be of fixed-size. Thus, the input volume for my dataset is prepared to be of shape `(1 x 100 x 4)` for each instance.

However, smote `fit_sample()` raised ValueError on passing the input data to resample. Here's my code (and output):

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import Counter
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))
sess = print(tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)))

#... class distributions
def class_distrib(arr):
    print('-' * 70)
    counter = Counter(arr)
    for c, v in sorted(counter.items() , key=lambda x: x[0]):
        per = v / len(arr) * 100
        print('Class=%s, Count=%d, Percentage=%.3f%%' % (c, v, per))
    print('-' * 70)

filename = 'keras_data.pickle'

with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
    Input, Label = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')  

NoClass = len(list(set(np.ndarray.flatten(Label))))
Instance_Length = len(Input[0, 0, :, 0])

Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y_ori = train_test_split(Input, Label, test_size=0.20)

print('-' * 70)
print('Input  shape before sampling: ' ,Train_X.shape, Train_Y.shape)
print('Class distribution before oversample: ')
class_distrib(Train_Y)

smote = SMOTE('minority')
Train_X, Train_Y = smote.fit_sample(Train_X, Train_Y)
print('Input shape after sampling: ' ,Train_X.shape, Train_Y.shape)

print('Class distribution after over-sampling: ')
class_distrib(Train_Y)

#...to categorical
Train_Y = keras.utils.to_categorical(Train_Y, num_classes=NoClass)
Test_Y = keras.utils.to_categorical(Test_Y_ori, num_classes=NoClass)

print('Label to categorical: ' ,Train_Y.shape)

model = Sequential()
activ = 'relu'
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=activ, input_shape=(1, Instance_Length, 4)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=activ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(NoClass, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(Train_X, Train_Y, epochs=50, batch_size=64, shuffle=False,
                         validation_data=(Test_X, Test_Y))
```

Error raised:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Input  shape before sampling:  (56646, 1, 100, 4) (56646,)
Class distribution before oversample: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Class=0, Count=29181, Percentage=51.515%
Class=1, Count=1513, Percentage=2.671%
Class=2, Count=1819, Percentage=3.211%
Class=3, Count=23814, Percentage=42.040%
Class=4, Count=319, Percentage=0.563%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smote_cnn.py", line 40, in <module>
    Train_X, Train_Y = smote.fit_sample(Train_X, Train_Y)

ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

I understand this is due to the input shape `(56646, 1, 100, 4)`, so I tried to flatten the input (n<sub>x</sub> `x` n<sub>y</sub>) right before calling smote `fit_sample()` this way:

```
#..reshape (flatten) Train_X for SMOTE resanpling
nsamples, k, nx, ny = Train_X.shape
Train_X = Train_X.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
```

This time, CNN's `conv2d-layer` raised ValueError, as the input shape is changed, output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Input  shape before sampling:  (56646, 1, 100, 4) (56646,)
Class distribution before oversample: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Class=0, Count=29181, Percentage=51.515%
Class=1, Count=1513, Percentage=2.671%
Class=2, Count=1819, Percentage=3.211%
Class=3, Count=23814, Percentage=42.040%
Class=4, Count=319, Percentage=0.563%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Input shape after sampling:  (85446, 400) (85446,)
Class distribution after over-sampling: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Class=0, Count=29106, Percentage=34.064%
Class=1, Count=1496, Percentage=1.751%
Class=2, Count=1858, Percentage=2.174%
Class=3, Count=23880, Percentage=27.947%
Class=4, Count=29106, Percentage=34.064%
----------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (85446, 400)
```

Can someone help point out how to use SMOTE here to resample the minority class without changing the input shape to the CNN model? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your question better suites StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite clear that after oversampling, you have input of shape $N_{samples}\times N_{features}$ and you didn't reshape it back to 4D tensor.

If your original data is tabular ($N_{samples}\times N_{features}$ plus one column as target) and you want to reshape only once, maybe you can restructure your data processing like this:

1. Train-test splitting first
2. Oversample the minority in training data
3. Reshape and dim-expand the training input to 4D tensor

For the reshaping, you can do some quick test using numpy:

```
x = np.random.rand(3, 1, 4, 10)
xr1 = x.reshape(3, 40)
xr2 = xr1.reshape(3, 1, 4, 10)

print(np.all(x == xr2))
```

You would see it prints 'True'. The reshaping works because numpy reads each element by c-like index (can be specified to F or A), and then reshapes the elements to the given shape.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I problem here is reshaping the input back to `(85446, 1, 100, 4)` from `(85446, 400)`. I struggle with this for couple of days.

Comment: @arilwan I updated with an example, hope it helps

Comment: @double this really help, many thanks.